# Show list items specific to user sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, moss, workflow, wss

In my project i have a asset list which contains "request to download" link. In the same list there is "download link" column which is default empty.

Now when any user clicks on request to download link a workflow is activated and it will send request to approver to approve or reject the download request.

If approver accept the request then the "download link" column in the asset list will be updated by some URL which redirect user to download page.

Now what happen is, if user A send request to download asset to approver and approver approves it this will update respective item in asset list and put a download URL in "Download Link" column but if user B get look for the same record in asset list the download link will be visible to this user too which is wrong.

I want to display download link columns value to only those user whos request has been approve.

FYI: I am using WSS 3.0

Can anyone help me what should be the best approch to do this...?

Thanks in Advance
Sachin

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide a field of a list item using SharePoint's built in interface.

Is it maybe possible to create two lists, "Assets" and "Download requests"? Download requests have a lookup to "Assets" list. In fact, this would also be more logical, since the approvers want to approve the requests, not the assets!

When a user requests download of an asset, you could create a new item in "Download requests" list which has approval enabled. When approver approves the request, you run a workflow that generates the download link. In the same moment you can `BreakRoleInheritance()` on the download request item and assign read permission only to the user who requested the download.

After the download is complete, you can even change the "Download request" status to complete or do whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

From your post I understud that you could complete the workflow and the issue only in the security.

This you can solve it with the following way

a. Set "Read only their own" option by go to the List settings-> advance settings->Item-level Permissions
b. Give the full control for approvers.